# Nuance between philia and mania?

Tags: word-usage, word-meaning

•to like something means to find something agreeable, enjoyable, or satisfactory.

•to have philia of something (eg. bibliophile)

means to have friendly feeling toward something or have an abnormal liking for something

( I want to know what that abnormality is)

•to be maniac of something (eg. anthomaniac)

means to be obsessed with something.

So what is the nuance between

abnormally liking something and being obsessed with something.

to me they sound the same.

Comment: Both "philia" and "mania" both are suffixes {Merriam-Webster), which are added to the end of a root word to make a new word; British call it combining form. "philia has 3 def's. 3 of 3. abnormal appetite or  liking for {something}  -mania is also a noun. def: (suffix) an excessive or unreasonable enthusiasm.  (noun) excitement ...by mental and physical hyperactivity, disorganization of behavior... Their root word can make them sound similar; but, they are different.

Comment: yes. But I want to know that difference.

Answer (score 6):

There are very different inferences.

The suffix *-philia* comes from one of the four ancient Greek words for *love*. In English the suffix is used to denote *love* or *affection*. For example, an *anglophile* is someone who loves England or things associated with it. There are other *negative* uses such as *paedophile*.

The suffix *-mania* does not mean "love" - it is synonymous with *obsession*. In fact "mania" is defined as a "*mental illness marked by periods of great excitement or euphoria, delusions, and overactivity*". As a suffix, it normally denotes an obsession, such as *Beatlemania* - the hysterical craze for the band The Beatles that existed in the 1960s. It does not have the negative connotation of a real mental illness. In fact, it is common to say one is "crazy for" something to mean they like it enthusiastically.

A clear difference is that a "mania" may pass. *Beatlemania* does not exist today as it did in the 1960s. A "mania" for something tends to be a group experience that is very much "of the moment". On the other hand, someone may be labelled "an Anglophile", which suggests that their love of something is not a passing fad but something deeper.

A quick bit of research reveals that some persons today do identify as "*Beatlemaniacs*", but that is really a throwback to a past era of widespread interest in The Beatles that does not really exist today on the same scale. Comparing that to the term "Anglophile" - when in recent times British music or British actors have held a larger than usual place in the US music/film industry there has been no notable use of the term "Anglo*philia*" to describe the phenomenon. Usually some other term like "British invasion" has been coined. Again, this suggests that "philia" is more appropriate to describe a personal experience rather than a widespread feeling.

Also, I believe that "mania" may imply some *action* or *motivation to action*. Again, an "anglophile" may have an interest or respect for England without ever actually visiting it. On the other hand a *pyromaniac* doesn't just *like* fires but has a compulsion to *create* them.

Some words that employ these suffixes have been in use for a very long time and the reasoning behind their creation may not be documented or easily explained. I would also go so far as to say (although this is purely an opinion) that the increased familiarity with the word *paedophile* may put people off using the *-philia* suffix to describe new phenomena.

Lastly, remember that some words are created *glibly*, perhaps as a marketing strategy (for example *Wrestlemania*) or to make newspaper headlines more interesting (eg "*Britain Braces for Beiber Mania!"). So despite all of the above regarding the true meaning and origins of the two suffixes, they may not always carry the full weight you might expect.

Comment: yeah. but isn't abnormally liking something and being obsessed with something, the same thing?

Comment: anglophilia= love for English and England. anglomania= craze or obsession with English and England.

Comment: @StewartGilliganGriffin I have just added a little which may answer this question.

Comment: okay. I think these are the degrees of liking something. For example if someone has staurophilia, going to a church or graveyard will evoke certain emotions inside him. But a stauromaniac would be someone who is obsessed with cross so much that he almost draws it everywhere. . just a thought , I may be wrong

Comment: @StewartGilliganGriffin Yes I think you've got it, although on the other hand the origins of words which employ one of these suffixes may also vary. The origins of words is not always documented.

Comment: any examples of such words? where the origin varies?

Comment: @StewartGilliganGriffin Perhaps terms like "Beatlemania" or "Wrestlemania" are glibly used, but they really do just refer to a frenzied interest in something, whereas "pyromania" means an actual compulsion to do something. Again, I've added more to my answer.

Comment: yes wrestlemania doesn't mean compulsion to actually punch someone .  I agree.   Now would you tell me the difference between merely liking something and having philia of it. For example I like reading books but not that much to be called a bibliophile.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/90255/discussion-between-astralbee-and-stewart-gilligan-griffin).